TypeError issue when trying to create a subclass of multiprocessing.Queue
I try to create a heritant subclass of multiprocessing.Queue as I did for queue.Queue, except I get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\d\multiprocessing-samples\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    class DataMultiProcQueue(multiprocessing.Queue):
TypeError: method expected 2 arguments, got 3

Here is the code to reproduce this error, I tested the error is present for Python 3.10, 3.11, 3.12.
import multiprocessing


class DataMultiProcQueue(multiprocessing.Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_queue = DataMultiProcQueue()
    my_queue.put(1)
    print(my_queue.get())

Am I missing something?

multiprocessing.Queue is actually the Queue factory method of an instance of the multiprocess.context.DefaultContext class.
(The namespace of the multiprocessing module is populated with all public members of this instance in multiprocessing/__init__.py upon importing the module.)
The real Queue class is multiprocessing.queues.Queue, so you would need to write:
import multiprocessing.queues

class DataMultiProcQueue(multiprocessing.queues.Queue):
    # …

I think it has been that way since at least Python 3.8.
